# maven build and run of a converted dynamic web project

Tags: maven, servlets, maven-plugin

new to maven/eclipse/java

1) created a new dynamic web project with eclipse.

2) created 2 servlets and 2 jsp (following this tutorial: http://blog.piraya.nl/2012/11/submitting-pdf-forms-in-java.html).

3) added the pom.xml file (copied from the tutorial) into the root of the project.

4) mavenized the project (Project->configure->convert to maven project)

5) run as maven install

6) run on server

this is the maven install output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PDFForms 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ PDFForms ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\eclipse-workspace\PDFForms\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ PDFForms ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ PDFForms ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\eclipse-workspace\PDFForms\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ PDFForms ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ PDFForms ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ PDFForms ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [PDFForms] in [D:\eclipse-workspace\PDFForms\target\PDFForms-1.0]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [52 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: D:\eclipse-workspace\PDFForms\target\PDFForms-1.0.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.469 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-05T08:31:02+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project PDFForms: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

this is the run on server output

```
INFORMAZIONI: Server startup in 9395 ms
apr 05, 2018 8:18:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: Marking servlet [PDFFormServlet] as unavailable
apr 05, 2018 8:18:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Allocate exception for servlet [PDFFormServlet]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.piraya.blog.PDFServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

this is the pom.xml copied from the tutorial

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>nl.piraya.blog</groupId>
   <artifactId>PDFForms</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <name>PDFForms</name>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.5</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
         <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.7</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.26</version>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

this is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

   <display-name>PDFForms</display-name>

   <!-- This servlet generates a PDF form on the fly. -->
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>PDFFormServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>PDFServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>PDFFormServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/dynamic.pdf</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <!-- This PDF accepts submitted FDF data. -->
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>FDFServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>nl.piraya.blog.FDFServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FDFServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/fdf</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <!-- Make sure the index.jsp file is opened when people access the application. -->
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does web.xml file exists in your project?

If servlet version less than 3.0 requires WEB-INF\web.xml compulsory
For version greater than or equal to 3.0 no web.xml and add the below dependency

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
```

Try adding this dependency in your pom.xml file.

Comment: The problem is not related cause the creation of the war file has been successfully being done...